# Some questions from a noob - Chat bot

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, ai

I'm a T-SQL and .NET developer but I need to understand some basis about a data science / ml project.
I would like to know the guidelines and be directed to the right topics about the steps that need the project.

The project would concern a chatbot (I would use the telegram api and on this point I already know how to do it) which, given n entities (e.g.: sales invoices, credit notes, customers, suppliers, etc.) present in the company database, gives answers based on user questions.
Example of questions:

- "I would like to know the items, quantity and total of the invoice FV23-XXXX"
- "how much did the customer bill in the last month?"
- "how much vendors supplied the item ITM-XXXX"
  What are the steps and courses to follow?
  How could the project be modeled?

I know that python is the best and most widespread language, so I would use that.

Unfortunately I don't have enough time to have the knowledge on the whole area to get an idea.
Forgive me for the stupid questions.